# ld: library not found for -lReactNativePayments

Tags: ios, xcode, react-native

I was upgrading the react native version for my project from 0.59.10 to 0.63.2 and since then I'm facing [this issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lwQ9h.png)

```
ld: library not found for -lReactNativePayments
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
```

when trying to run the project or build it from xcode, I tried almost all solutions I found but nothing changed

my Podfile contains:

```
require_relative '../node_modules/react-native/scripts/react_native_pods'
require_relative '../node_modules/@react-native-community/cli-platform-ios/native_modules'
platform :ios, '10.0'
...
pod 'ReactNativePayments', :path => '../node_modules/react-native-payments'
```

I'm running .xcworkspace and library search paths are empty

any help would be appreciated, thanks in advance

Comment: did your run pod install ?

Comment: yes, more than once and it gave me that installation completed